# tsql: table data size won't shrink after large row deletion

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, dbcc

i have a table with 12 months+ data in it.
I backup the table then delete all rows keeping only rows inserted in the last month.
But the table size won't shrink, nor the underlying physical file.

```
dbcc showcontig ('mytable') with tableresults;

ObjectName  ObjectId    IndexName   IndexId Level   Pages   Rows    MinimumRecordSize   MaximumRecordSize   AverageRecordSize   ForwardedRecords    Extents ExtentSwitches  AverageFreeBytes    AveragePageDensity  ScanDensity BestCount   ActualCount LogicalFragmentation    ExtentFragmentation
mytable 478624748   PK_Log  1   0   21344   467392  94  8033    237 0   2675    12918   2862,346    64,6361996540647    20,6517532316743    2668    12919   77,8392053973013    71,7757009345794


exec sp_spaceused 'mytable', @updateusage = 'TRUE'

name    rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
LogTrace    467392      8984976 KB  8930056 KB  21984 KB    32936 KB
```

These values means each row of the table is about 19MB!

I tryed to rebuild the index with no change:
    ALTER INDEX PK_myindex ON mytable REBUILD

Other things i tryed:

```
select
[FileSizeMB]    =
    convert(numeric(10,2),round(a.size/128.,2)),
[UsedSpaceMB]   =
    convert(numeric(10,2),round(fileproperty( a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.,2)) ,
[UnusedSpaceMB] =
    convert(numeric(10,2),round((a.size-fileproperty( a.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.,2)) ,
GrowthPct   =
    case when a.status & 0x00100000 = 1048576 then a.growth else null end,
GrowthMB    =
    convert(int,round(case when a.status & 0x00100000 = 1048576 then null else a.growth /128.000 end,0)),   
[DBFileName]    = a.name
from
sysfiles a;
```

result

```
FileSizeMB  UsedSpaceMB UnusedSpaceMB   GrowthPct   GrowthMB    DBFileName
9742.38 9740.06 2.31    NULL    1   mytable
72.25   15.45   56.80   NULL    1   mytable_log
3.00    0.06    2.94    NULL    1   mytable_indexes
```

I don't know what to do more, any idea ?

Comment: Table definition including index definitions might be helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ALTER INDEX ALL ON mytable REBUILD`

With the index size value being so high, this points to a non-clustered index. Clustered index size is very small usually.

You can check with the `all_indexes` parameter when using the DBCC SHOWCONTIG command:

```
dbcc showcontig ('Risk') with all_indexes, tableresults;
```

For example, one of my tables. A billion rows, 70GB table, 450MB index

```
name      rows       reserved  data     index_size  unused
BigTable  1041302384 71256288  70793880 460832      1576
```

Note that deleted records are not physically removed on DELETE. A "ghost clean up" process does that afterwards.

Comment: you were right of course. I used the IndexOptimize sp from http://ola.hallengren.com/ to automate this work for all index on all tables on all db.

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink that database files through the Enterprise Manager. Right click on the database,  All Tasks->Shrink Database

Comment: Won't help to defrag/reclaim space